# Sectioning off image in python

Tags: python, image, edit

I have made a program that is taking an image I uploaded and dividing it into quadrants to mess with the colour in each one differently. My problem is that I can't see to get the division right.

```
import cImage as image

img = image.Image("/home/users/groth1/Downloads/selfie.JPG")

newimg = image.EmptyImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())

win = image.ImageWin(title="Pic",width=img.getWidth(),height=img.getHeight())

for row in range(img.getHeight(0,186)):  #Negative Q1
    for col in range(img.getWidth(0,325)):
       p = img.getPixel(col, row)

    newred = 255 - p.getRed()
    newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
    newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()

    newpixel = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

    img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
```

when I run this (with intro code introducing image and all that) I get an error that says "TypeError: getHeight() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given" 
What does that mean? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that the functions `cImage.Image.getHeight` and `cImage.Image.getHeight` are meant to be called without any positional arguments.  They just return the height and width of the image.  I don't understand what you were trying to achieve by passing in `0`, `186`, and `325`.  Here's an idea for how to fix up your code:

```
xQuadrantBoundary = img.getWidth()//2
yQuadrantBoundary = img.getHeight()//2

for row in range(img.getHeight()):  #Negative Q1
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)

        if row < yQuadrantBoundary:
            if col < xQuadrantBoundary:
                # Change this to what you want to happen to the colors in the upper left
                newred = 255 - p.getRed()
                newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
                newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()
            elif col >= xQuadrantBoundary:
                # Change this to what you want to happen to the colors in the upper right
                newred = 255 - p.getRed()
                newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
                newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()
        elif row >= yQuadrantBoundary:
            if col < xQuadrantBoundary:
                # Change this to what you want to happen to the colors in the lower left
                newred = 255 - p.getRed()
                newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
                newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()
            elif col >= xQuadrantBoundary:
                # Change this to what you want to happen to the colors in the lower right
                newred = 255 - p.getRed()
                newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
                newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()

        newpixel = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
```